# Is "on deadline" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

For example:

> I wrote reports on deadline.

I am trying to say that I met deadlines.

Comment: "On deadline" just means that a deadline existed, not that you successfully met it!

Comment: Asking about "is it grammatically correct" may not be the right question.  I think you want to know if your example is clear and has the intended meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is grammatically correct

However, The phrase you are "trying to say" would be better: "met deadlines".

> I met all deadlines for writing reports.

I'm not totally certain if this is appropriate for a resume; It sounds like claiming "I did my job", which is the minimum expectation.  It's not really an "achievement".

Answer (score 1):

Very common idiomatic expressions by reporters include the phrase "on deadline." It's jargon in the news industry. Some examples:

*Don't bother me, I'm on deadline.*

*I do my best work when I'm on deadline.*

*The editor really gets nervous when we're on deadline for the last edition.*

To be less idiomatic, these sentences should probably include an article (a) and a verb phrase in place of the preposition "on." For example:

"I work better when I have a deadline"

"Don't bother me, I am working against a deadline."

For something like a cover letter or resume, I personally would not mind the sentence "I wrote reports on deadline." However, some might say that it is more formal grammar to write, "I wrote reports under deadline pressure" or "I wrote reports and met strict deadlines."

Comment: You could also say that you wrote the reports **_to_** deadlines which implies that you completed them within the target times.